# Closing a gen_tcp listen socket that is owned by an OTP supervisor

Tags: tcp, erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

A few tutorials, including this [*Learn You Some Erlang*](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets) one, show applications where an OTP supervisor will open and own a TCP listen socket and share it to a number of workers, who will accept connections.

My question is, how do you close a listen socket owned by a supervisor without a terminate/2 callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket is linked to the process that owns it.  If that process exits, the socket is automatically closed.  (This goes for both listening sockets and connection sockets.)

(The process that owns the socket is the process that created it, unless you've called `gen_tcp:controlling_process` to reassign ownership of the socket.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do they close automatically regardless of whether the process exits normally or abnormally?

Comment: Yes, it's the same in both cases.